# Action filter execution order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter, authorize-attribute

I have created two classes that implement `AuthorizeAttribute`.

One is used globally, and I set it on the Global.asax.cs:

```
filters.Add(new FirstAuthorizeAttribute() { Order = 0 });
```

The other is called `SecondAuthorizeAttribute` and it is used only in some action methods, and I use it as attribute in the methods I want.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [SecondAuthorize]
    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
    }
```

The problem is that `SecondAuthorizeAttribute` always execute before `FirstAuthorizeAttribute`, and I need this one to execute first. The order is not being helpful, how could I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a long shot, but have you tried using the Global and First values for your  FirstAuthorizeAttribute ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterscope(v=vs.98).aspx

http://blog.rajsoftware.com/post/2011/05/14/MVC3-Filter-Ordering.aspx

Comment: Please consider copying the relevant content from the links into the answer.

Answer (score 28):

The link in @HectorCorrea's answer is dead at the moment, here's the content retrieved and summarised from the current Google cache (in case that also goes) :

Filters execute in this order:

- Authorization filters
- Action filters
- Response/Result filters
- Exception filters

Within each filter, you may specify the Order property. (All filters are derived from the abstract class FilterAttribute, and this class has an Order property). This property will ensure the filter runs in a specific Order.

eg:

```
[AuthorizationFilterA(Order=2)]
[AuthorizationFilterB(Order=1)]
public ActionResult Index()
{          
    return View();
}
```

There's also `FilterScope` and, by default, the filter with the lowest scope runs first when the order is the same (or not specified):

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc {
    public enum FilterScope {
        First = 0,
        Global = 10,
        Controller = 20,
        Action = 30,
        Last = 100,
    }
}
```

If no order is specified, the order value is -1 (first, not last).

Controllers themselves can be filters and will run with order `Int32.MinValue`

Comment: Bear in mind that Exception filters run in reverse order (of course they do!), so for those, the filter with the highest scope runs first

Answer (score 3):

Order is not working in global.asax.cs file.
If requirement is order then goto Controller or Action Method and give.
ex:-

[secondAttribute(order =1)]
[firstAttribute(order=2)]

HomeController:Controller

or

public ActionResult Index()