# How can I control the execution order of Authorization Policy Attributes in relation to MVC AuthorizeFilter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization

Currently I have the following configurations for a asp.net core 2.1 project in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //... some other configs
    
    services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            var authorizeFilter = new AuthorizeFilter(policy);
            options.Filters.Add(authorizeFilter);
        });
        
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("PolicyA", builder =>
                builder.Requirements.Add(new RequirementA()));
            options.AddPolicy("PolicyB", builder =>
                builder.Requirements.Add(new RequirementB()));
        });
    
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "authority";
                options.Audience = "audience";
            });
    //... some more configs
}
```

and also a Controller that starts like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy="PolicyA"]
[Authorize(Policy="PolicyB"]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    // super awesome code I can't show :P
}
```

My goal is to **execute** the **AuthorizeFilter** that handles the basic Bearer authentication and authorization **before "PolicyA" and "PolicyB"**. At the moment it seams like the AuthorizeFilter is executed last after "PolicyA" and "PolicyB".

I already looked into similar issues posted here, but I only found solutions for setting the execution order of Attributes, but I want to use the MVC filter if possible instead of an attribute for the basic authentication and authorization.

So this one unfortunately didn't help me: [Action filter execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890610/action-filter-execution-order)

---

**Update:**
As Xerillio suggested in the comments that policies are probably meant to be self-contained, I adapted my AuthorizationHandlers to also check what my AuthorizeFilter is checking already. This does not feel like the best possible solution, but I will keep it for now.

Comment: If your policies require the user to be authenticated, then you should add that to the policies. I think policies are meant to be self-contained and not dependent on each other.

Comment: But i.e. the AuthorizeFilter checks for username and password being correct which is being required everywhere in the application. Additionally I want to have different policies for specific requirements i.e. a specific user role like admin that can access the AdminController. What would be the best way to implement this? When I the requirements can't depend on each other I will need to duplicate or at least reference the same code in every IAuthorizationHandler. I think there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: If your policies are about requiring the user to have a specific role, then you should look at [role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and not policies.

Comment: Role-based authorization does not solve my problem here, because it is not any different to using policies in their execution behavior and order. I didn't use role-based authorization here because it ist more limited in functionality, but that is a different topic...