# What is the execution order of global filters MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

I have 2 global action filters in my MVC 4 application, that I've registered in Filter.config file using RegisterGlobalFilters. I need them to be executed in a particular order.

I know how to specify order for Controller specific filters but how do I specify order and scope for my global filters? is it in the order in which they are registered?

Comment: This is a great resource for filtering in MVC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6561914/290343

Comment: @asymptoticFault, Ofer Zelig: Thanks for the links! They both give order of the different type of filters but not order within global filters. Where I am struggling is how to set order property of global filters because i need my global filters to execute in a particular order. :)

Answer (score 12):

As no answer has thusfar been given about how to specify the order of global filters in RegisterGlobalFilters, here's my answer:

You can specify the order in the Add method, by passing in a second parameter:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute(), 1);
    filters.Add(new LogFilter(), 2);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[In this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) scroll down to the **Filter Order** section.  There are the `Order` and `Scope` properties that allow you to control the execution order.