# ASP.NET MVC & Angular: After session expires, Angular Factory returns HTML of Login Page instead of JSON object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

If the user is on a page for a long time and the session ends, if they proceed to make an AJAX call after the session is already expired.. instead of receiving the JSON object, it instead receives the HTML of the login page.

Ideally I'm trying to make it so that it will redirect to a log in page.

Is there any way i can detect this?

I already have an ActionFilterAttribute that works for non-AJAX calls like so:

```
public class VerifySessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var userId = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserId"];
        var userName = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserName"];

        if (userId == null || userName == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(string.Format("/Account/Login"));
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

But that doesn't get hit for the scenario above during AJAX calls.

I've also tried an Interceptor.. something like this:

```
app.factory('httpAuthInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function (response) {
            // NOTE: detect error because of unauthenticated user
            if ([401, 403].indexOf(response.status) >= 0) {
                // redirecting to login page
                //$state.go('home');
                $window.location.href = '/Account/Login';
                return response;
            } else {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    };
})

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpAuthInterceptor');
});
```

But in the same scenario it doesn't seem to hit there as well during the expired session / AJAX call

Is there anything I can do to detect this?  When the session is expired I just want to redirect to the login page..  Thanks for any help

EDIT:  here's how I make my calls

```
app.factory('HeadlinesFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var HeadlinesFactory = {};

    HeadlinesFactory.getShowsForClient = function (clientId) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Show/GetShowsForClient',
            data: { clientId: JSON.stringify(clientId) }
        });
    };
    //etc
```

EDIT2: how all my controllers look like.  Except my Account Controller where I put the VerifySession in front of everything except the Login page to prevent loop redirects:

```
[Authorize]
[CustomFilters.VerifySession]
public class ShowController : Controller
{ ... }
```

Comment: As your return `RedirectResult` it means that response status will be 302 thus you should check status on 302 in your interceptor.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thanks for your input.  from my testing, it seems like when the session is expired and i'm trying to make an AJAX call it, it doesn't go into the interceptor at all, so no matter what I put in there it doesn't matter because of that.  Please though if I'm wrong about that and maybe doing something incorrectly let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax requests will not process redirect requests for security reasons.  In addition, since you are returning a redirect result, a 401/403 status code is not thrown but rather a 302 is returned.

What you could do is expand your filter to conditionalize logic based on whether or not the request is an ajax request.  In addition, based on your comments, it seems like creating a new Authorize attribute instead would be the right way to go since that way you can simply replace the default Authorize attribute with your own logic.

```
public class VerifySessionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = 
                      true;
            }
            else 
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(string.Format("/Account/Login"));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow your Angular interceptor to pick up the request and handle it appropriately.

Since IsAjaxRequest looks explicitly for the "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" and AngularJS no longer provides that header with Ajax requests, you can add a configuration to the $httpProvider to always include the header.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

Comment: Hey David thanks for responding.  I put a break point in my ActionFilter that I posted above and it seems like it doesn't go in there AT ALL once the session has expired, so I feel like that wouldn't work... am I wrong?  I want you to be correct lol.  I actually did try that with no avail unfortunately

Comment: How are you applying your attribute?  Is it being used in conjunction with `[Authorize]` attributes?

Comment: Yes.  I put it preceding all my Controllers.  I made an EDIT2 to show you

Comment: If your user is already expired (and logged out), the Authorize attribute will catch it before hand and prevent the request from ever reaching your custom filter.  In this case, you probably need to remove the Authorize attribute and allow your Custom Filters to handle authorization in all cases.

Comment: Ah that's interesting I never thought about it like that.  Real quick, does putting the Custom Filter ABOVE the [Authorize] cause it to filter through Custom first?  I'm going to try out your suggestion right now

Comment: No, unfortunately the order that they are listed does not help.  The rules are more complex than that.  If you look through the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6561914/1165998 you'll find that Authorize filters will run before Action Filters, meaning that even if you use the Order property for your attribute, it would run after Authorize, unless you also made your filter an Authorize attribute or converted your filter into an override of the Authorize attribute.

Comment: hm, that makes for complications because I definitely don't want to just remove the [Authorize] attritube.. i'll look into making it an Authorize attribute as well?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1189352 I've updated my answer to use an Authorize attribute filter example.  With that filter you could essentially replace the `[Authorize]` attribute if you wanted to.

Comment: i'm not sure why but it seems like if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) isn't returning TRUE.. do you know why?  I'm just clicking a button on my page that's hitting the Factory i posted above then goes there.  It's messing this whole thing up

Comment: My apologies, it's been a while since I looked at IsAjaxRequest and my memory was foggy.  I've updated my answer with additional information in regards to adding the needed header.

Comment: ah i jus found that the second you updated and it worked.  okay i think that's all i needed.  David you're a wizard man thank you so much. I've actually been stuck on this for a couple days now.. you've really helped me.  Thank you

Comment: @user1189352 glad to help!  Sorry we had to go round and round a bit but it all came together in the end :)