# Are ASP.NET MVC filters (of the same type) executed in the order they are included in code, and is that guaranteed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

When including MVC filters, I understand that they can be registered in the following **locations**

1. Global (FilterConfig.cs)
2. Controller Level
3. Action level

I also know that there are 4 **types** and that they are executed in the following order:

1. Authorization filters
2. Action filters
3. Response filters
4. Exception filters

However, I'm a little confused on priority here:

- Are the locations executed in the order shown?
- Assuming that the location is executed in order, which takes priority: type or location?
- What happens if multiple filters of the same type are declared in the same location? Are they executed in the order they are defined?

For example if I have 6 filters as below, in what order will they be executed?

```
// FilterConfig.cs
filters.Add(new AuthorizationFilter());
filters.Add(new ActionFilter());
```

-

```
// MyController.cs
[AuthorizationFilter2]
[ActionFilter2]
public class MyController
{ 
    [AuthorizationFilter3]
    [ActionFilter3]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
         return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what order are filters executed in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561883/in-what-order-are-filters-executed-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @HasanElsherbiny partly, but I'm still unclear on the order of filters added in RegisterGlobalFilters, for example