# AuthCookie is set, still being redirected to login.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, mixed-authentication

I'm setting up mixed mode authentication in a C# web app. I set the AuthCookie in the WindowsAuthentication website and then try to redirect to the FormsAuthentication website. I think the cookie is in the correct path and everything because Context.Request.IsAuthenticated is true. Unfortunately, I keep getting redirected to the login page of the FormsAuthentication website as if I haven't set the AuthCookie. What is going on?

I'm not familiar with how authentication works in ASP.NET so please, explain it to me like I'm 5. Thanks, :)

edit: Here is the event in the Global.asax of the WindowsAuth site that makes the cookie. This site currently resides in the path /authentication "under" the FormsAuth site.

> ```
> void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     WindowsIdentity ident = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
>     WindowsPrincipal p = new WindowsPrincipal(ident);
>     if (p.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
>     {
>         HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(p.Identity.Name, false);
>         FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
>         // Store roles inside the Forms cookie.
>         FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
>             ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration,
>             ticket.IsPersistent, "", ticket.CookiePath);
>         string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
>         Context.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(".GWBTroubleTickets", encTicket));
>     }
>     Response.Redirect("/employee/home.aspx");
> }
> ```

Comment: Do you have any code snippets you can share?

Comment: I wasn't sure what code to post at first, but edited there is basically it.

Comment: The best approach is to use an http debugger to sniff requests and see if the cookie reaches the forms site. If yes, then probably crypto keys are different on both machines so the cookie cannot be decrypted or the cookie name is just wrong. If no, then you'd have to analyze the flow to see what is the cause of the missing cookie.

Comment: ScottieMc It doesn't cause a problem since that PostAuthenticateRequest is on a different site and the redirect goes to the main site.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The cookie is reaching the forms site and "IsAuthenticated". In other words, I have verified that the same user credentials are reaching the forms site. The problem is that the cookie *is* there on the forms site but I keep getting redirected to the login page.

Comment: Are you having two different applications, one running inside another? In that case, you should probably hard code the encryption keys in the web.configs so both applications use the same key

Comment: @Onkelborg Yep, the machine keys and validation keys are identical. I don't think the problem is in the cookie itself. There's some problem with... I have no clue. I should be able to go FormsAuthentication.setAuthCookie("blah", true) and that's it, right?

Comment: What's the value of CookiePath? Try to attach a debugger and see what's really happening

Comment: Still, attach a debugger and see what's really happening

Comment: What domain have you configured for the cookie? If they are running on seperate URL's and the cookie is issued for the first domain then the cookie wont be posted to the other application. eg.  

    <httpCookies domain="www.magic.com" />  

Will only produce cookies that will be posted to that domain, so if your other app is at www.sparkle.com the forms auth cookie wont be posted

Answer (score 0):

The event may be called many times per page. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947309/57883
You don't have an `if/else` surrounding the `Response.Redirect("/employee/home.aspx");`

Try using a custom attribute instead of this event