# Mixing Windows Authentication with SQL Server Custom Authentication MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, windows-authentication

I would like authenticate the user based on User.Identity.Name and get the other detail from SQL Server database like Role and last loggedin date, etc.

After login i should authorize the same user for subsequent calls without hitting database.

However i hit and load the user information at initial login and i stored in session.

Here is my SQL Table

**ApplicationUser**

- UserId -> windows identity name mapping stored here
- Display Name
- RoleId
- LastLoginDate
- IsActive

Login Controller logic

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
 string userId = User.Identity.Name;
    userId = userId.Substring(userId.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
    var key = "Roles." + userId;
    var roles = HttpContext.Cache[key]
    if (roles == null)
    {
        User user = AdminService.SelectUser(userId);
        roles = new string[] { user.Role.RoleName };
        HttpContext.Cache.Add(key, roles, null,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(HttpContext.Session.Timeout),
            Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

        HttpContext.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new
                    GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, roles);
        HttpContext.Session["LoggedInUser"] = user;
    }
}
```

Also i have the below code to authorize a user on each requestin MVC3

```
void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    string userId = User.Identity.Name;
    userId = userId.Substring(userId.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
    var key = "Roles." + userId;
    var roles = HttpContext.Cache[key];
    if (roles != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.User =
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal =
                new GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, roles);
    }
}
}
```

But i advised to change this above logic, as i am getting an issue while accessing the User object stored in a session. I have no idea why it is like that.

Do any one have **other possible code/logic to do the above mixed authentication?**

**Edit:** I was getting error in accessing HttpContext.Session["LoggedInUser"] in some other controller method.

Answer (score 1):

> as i am getting an issue while accessing the User object stored in a session.

You are not storing the info in a session. You are storing it in the Cache. That's your problem. The Cache is shared between all users of your application. So instead of using `HttpContext.Cache` you could use the `HttpContext.Session`.

Alternatively to using sessions and caches you could store thisinformation inside the UserData portion of the forms authentication cookie as I have [illustrated in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947309/29407).

Comment: I updated my question. I store user information in session for accessing later. But getting an error sometime. I got something bad with my code. I dont know what is going wrong. I referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947278/when-postauthenticaterequest-gets-execute your old answer and trying to follow

Comment: Great, that's an approach I would recommend you.

Comment: That is fine. But using FormsAuthenticationTicket combined with Windows Authentication will not make any issue i think. Is it right?