# Custom Role Manager / Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, forms-authentication, roleprovider

I am trying to implement a custom role manager in an MVC5 application using the following [Custom Role Provider Tutorial](http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC).

I have created my Custom Role Provider overiding the 2 required functions.

```
namespace Models.Security
{
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
/// logic
 public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
/// logic
public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
```

I then need to alter my web config to use this new provider...

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
 <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Models.Security.CustomRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

However when I try and access my application I get the following error:

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Models.Security.CustomRoleProvider'.

```
Source Error:

Line 29:       <providers>
Line 30:         <clear />
Line 31:         <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Models.Security.CustomRoleProvider"/>
Line 32:       </providers>
Line 33:     </roleManager>
```

As far as I am aware I have done everything that is required. The only thing that is different is I am using a custom membership linking to AD

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="200" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Is there something else I need to do? Has MVC5 changed the approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. MVC 5 uses Identity, Role providers are an ASP.NET Membership concept. You don't need role providers in Identity, because *you* control the roles. It's an entity in your project (or at least it can be if you subclass `IdentityRole`), so you can do whatever you want.

Comment: So is there an easy way to move between the two? All examples I've found on/using Identity Role span pages! I've got custom tables with roles and actions created which I want to check against an Authorization attribute on an Action. I really want to save all the roles against my UserPrincipal object when logging in and then use that throughout the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use roleManager and your custom role provider. Just have to set your principal to type RolePrincipal. You can do that on IAuthenticationFilter and register it on global.asax. See those two links for some sample code: 
[RolePrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16750321/1133338) /
[IAuthenticationFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16746264/1133338)