# Custom Role Provider, Unity, and Service Locator Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I'm have a similar set up to this question [MVC Custom ROles Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499821/custom-role-manager-provider).  I have created my custom roles provider. but I would like to Use Unity IOC like the rest of my project.  I have tried to Implement the Service Locator pattern for this and I am very new to this concept. I was following this guidance [Custom Roles Fine Print](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2009/05/11/tip-entity-framework-unity-and-the-asp-net-roleprovider-read-the-msdn-fine-print/)  and this is where I'm stuck.

Here is my WebConfig Role Manager Section

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Reconciliation.CustomRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />   </providers> 
</roleManager>
```

I am using a UnityMvcActivator Start Class as follows. The Start() class is in an external Class library. and it is referenced through from my UI project. That set up my Dependency Injection

```
using CommonServiceLocator;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Unity.AspNet.Mvc;
using Unity.ServiceLocation;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Bootstrapper.UnityMvcActivator), nameof(Bootstrapper.UnityMvcActivator.Start))]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(Bootstrapper.UnityMvcActivator), nameof(Bootstrapper.UnityMvcActivator.Shutdown))]

namespace Bootstrapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with ASP.NET MVC.
    /// </summary>
    public static class UnityMvcActivator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Integrates Unity when the application starts.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var locator = new UnityServiceLocator(UnityConfig.Container);

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(UnityConfig.Container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container));

            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            //Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));

            bool AlwasyTrue = ServiceLocator.IsLocationProviderSet;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            UnityConfig.Container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

var AlwasyTrue = ServiceLocator.IsLocationProviderSet;  Always True here;

```
In my Custom Roles Provider Class I have 
using System;
using System.Web.Security;
using Core.Interfaces;
using Unity.ServiceLocation;   <--
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
 bool alwaysFalse = ServiceLocator.IsLocationProviderSet;
    ICustomRoleProviderService roleService =
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ICustomRoleProviderService>();
        return roleService.GetRolesForUser(username);
        }
    }
```

bool alwaysFalse = ServiceLocator.IsLocationProviderSet; < Always false here, and is always called after the Unity Start() class.

But it throws the error 
[image]

I'm not entirely sure how to fix it. It t says that I need to set my service location provider. I believe the issue has something to do with the Unity IOC being in an external class. It works for DI in other classes but not for Dependency Resolver / service locator in the RolesManager... Stumped.... Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved Turns Out that the issue was in fact exactly what the Error was saying. In the External UnityMvcActivator Class I was using

```
using CommonServiceLocator;
```

and in the CustomRoleProvider class I was using

```
using Unity.ServiceLocation;
```

I ended up changing out that one Reference and rebuilt and it works as expected. Took awhile to find this. Hope this helps someone else if they run into this.